# print params each in curl

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i need to increment the userb and usere but when i write my variable in curl , and when i try it i get nothing

```
(1..180000).step(20000)do |userb|
 (20000..180000).step(20000)do |usere|
curl = %x[ curl -i -s -H "Host: xxxx" "http://XXXXX/scripts/exportStatsCsv/testA1?start='+ userb +'&end='+ usere +'&startDate='#{@array_timestampdate[0]}'&endDate='#{@array_timestampdate[1]}'" ]                                                                                                 sleep(10)  
  end 
end
```

Comment: Define "get nothing".

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code with warnings and debugging turned on:

```
ruby -cW2 path/to/your/code
```

You should see something like:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...                          sleep(10)
...                               ^
```

You need to do this as a first step when you run into a problem. Ruby will give you more detailed information about problems with the script when warnings are enabled and set to their highest value. Here's what the flags mean:

```
  -c              check syntax only
  -W[level=2]     set warning level; 0=silence, 1=medium, 2=verbose
```

You're getting this error, because `sleep(10)` needs to be executed as a separate statement. You can either insert `;` between it, and the call to cURL, or put it on its one line. I'd recommend the second option in order to make the commands easier to read.

Also, I'd highly recommend using the [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem instead of launching cURL in a sub-shell like you are. You're losing flexibility and wasting CPU time having Ruby, then the OS, create a new shell to launch cURL.

Finally, you need to learn to write your code more clearly or you'll paint yourself into corners of confusion in no time. Here's a starting point for how I'd write the code:

```
require 'uri'

@array_timestampdate = ['start_date', 'end_date']

(1..180000).step(20000) do |userb|
  (20000..180000).step(20000) do |usere|

    uri = URI.parse('http://XXXXX/scripts/exportStatsCsv/testA1')
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(
      {
        'start'     => userb,
        'end'       => usere,
        'startDate' => @array_timestampdate[0],
        'endDate'   => @array_timestampdate[1]
      }
    )
    curl = %Q[ curl -i -s -H "Host: xxxx" "#{uri.to_s}" ]

    puts curl
  end 
end
```

With a little example of the output:

```
>> curl -i -s -H "Host: xxxx" "http://XXXXX/scripts/exportStatsCsv/testA1?start=1&end=20000&startDate=start_date&endDate=end_date"
...
>> curl -i -s -H "Host: xxxx" "http://XXXXX/scripts/exportStatsCsv/testA1?start=160001&end=180000&startDate=start_date&endDate=end_date"
```

Comment: i found s solution to my problem you can find below the solution  curl = %x[ curl -i -s -H 'Host: xxxx' "http://xxxxx/scripts/Stats/testA1?start=#{userb}&end=#{usere}&startDate='#{@array_timestampdate[0]}'&endDate='#{@array_tim    estampdate[1]}'" ]